# Trying to Load on Template Image Uploaded to ImageField

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-templates, django-urls

With the Code Below all that renders in the alt option of the image...
The code works if I hardcode the below HTML statment with the actual filepath of the image : src"media/media/image.jpg.
This is my html statement:

```
<img class="first-slide" src="media/{{Home.slide_1.photo.url}}" alt="First slide">
```

This is my Models.py:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media/', default = 'media/None/no-img.jpg')
    photo_caption = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    photo_description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    master_album = models.ManyToManyField('Album', related_name="album")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = PhotoManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.photo_caption

class Home(models.Model):
    slide_1 = models.ManyToManyField('Photo', related_name="slide_1")
    slide_2 = models.ManyToManyField('Photo', related_name="slide_2")
    slide_3 = models.ManyToManyField('Photo', related_name="slide_3")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: right Click on the image -> inspect element. What is the value of `src`?

Comment: @hansTheFranz src = "media/"